# Hibernate - Open session per view with multiple sessionfactories

Tags: hibernate, view, sessionfactory

Does anyone have any examples for how to implement open-session-per-view pattern with multiple sessionfactories. My application queries 3 databases. Some views need to be rendered by calls to all three databases.